# How can I hide parts of a row header in a fast report crosstab object?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

I have a report with a crosstab object on it which looks like this:
[image]

Based on user choice, I want to hide the second column. Since it is part of my report's row header, `OnCalcWidth()` is not called and I can't set its `Width` to 0. I tried accessing it using its name, but apparently child objects inside a `TDBCrossTab` are neither accessible in fast report scripts nor in Delphi. (`frxReport.Page[1].FindObject('DBCross1Corner4')` and `frxReport.Page[1].FindObject('DBCross1').FindObject('DBCross1Corner4')` both return `nil`).

I'm using Fast Report 4.13.1

Any ideas?